# Glassfish Datasource Not found only on mac

Tags: java, macos, netbeans, glassfish

I'm working on a simple project and I'm using Netbeans. I want to make an entity from the database, and use it (basics).

I have a simple Netbeans project and it works perfectly on a PC, but when I move to my mac an exception appears : `javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for...`

- I have the same database name and root password on both mac and pc.
- The project work perfectrly on my pc.

Comment: Does the glassfish server installed on your mac have the jdbc resources configured ?? That is to say the JNDI name configured for your datasources ?

Comment: If all you did was copy the project then probably no datasource/pool/resource-ref was created in the domain.xml, and the server may not have the necessary jdbc driver jar either.